# How do I convert a cell that has only a year (probably a string) into DateTime datatype?

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, insert, converters

I've got cells in an excel file that contain data like:

"2006","2005","2015"

It is read into a datagridview temporarily, which is later inserted into an access database like so:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Con))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        "Insert INTO ACTB (ID,Business,Account,Description,Span_Year,Period,Amount_PHP,Project_Number,Status_Regime,Department,Description_Dept,Accounts,Class) " +
        "VALUES(@ID,@Business,@Account,@Description,@Span_Year,@Period,@Amount_PHP,@Project_Number,@Status_Regime,@Department,@Description_Dept,@Accounts,@Class)";
        for (int s = 0; s < DGVExcel.Rows.Count; s++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            int theDoubleDate = Convert.ToInt32(DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[4].Value);
            DateTime theDate = DateTime.FromOADate(theDoubleDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business_Unit", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[2].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[3].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Span_Year", theDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[5].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount_PHP", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[6].Value == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[6].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Number", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[7].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status_Regime", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[8].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[9].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description_Dept", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[10].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IS_Accounts", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[11].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITR_Class", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[12].Value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

However, these write the values wrong, like 8/7/1905 all ending in 1905.

Another requirement is that the end value be day and month agnostic, meaning the value would come up as say: 2016 => 1/1/2016, just before the data is inserted into the database. Some have suggested that I merely use int values, however, datetime is required for me because I intend to use the `between` keyword to easily look up data between certain periods.

Edit: I just realized that some of my data might not have a year listed. Normally, I could be able to insert nulls just fine, however, if I'm doing some convert before that, I'm sure it will throw an exception like Cannot convert DB.Null into other types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there is a value in the cell and then create a new `DateTime`

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[3].Value))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Span_Year", DateTime.Now.Date);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Span_Year", new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[3].Value), 1, 1);
}
```

I would also recommend specifying the datatype in the parameter, this will provide more type-safety and prevent conversion errors with datetime.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 45;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Span_Year", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked after adjusting the first condition with a .ToString() and a parenthesis on the second condition's parameter add.